# How to make all activities(except MainActivity) have ActionBar/Toolbar at once with the title of the Activity and a back button?

Tags: android, set, android-actionbar

I have the following `MainActivity`:

[image]

When I click on "Congreso" button the following activity appears:

[image]

And when I click on "Programa" button the following activity appears:

[image]

All activities except `MainActivity` have an action bar with a back button, a title of the activity aligned at the same place each time and the same color of the action bar. In my case I want the color to be blue. My question is, is there a way to set that behaviour on a single place in the application and it to apply to all the activities except for the `MainActivity` so that if some day I want to change the color of the action bar or the alignement of its title I don't have to go to all activities one by one and change it.

P.S.: I don't know if what is on the screenshots is an action bar or it is a toolbar. If you give me a solution with a toolbar it is OK too.

Comment: If `color` is the only concern then store the color in `res` and use from there.

Comment: Please make a BaseActivity , Use the Action bar in BaseActivity , Handle "Back Image Click" there and just set the respective title name in Individual Activities. All the Activities will extends BaseActivity excluding MainActivity

Comment: I can't do that in `.axml` , right? I have to do it programatically in code?

Comment: no , you need to use BaseActivity (Inheritance). As it will be easy to implement and a generic solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please make a BaseActivity , Use the Action bar in BaseActivity , Handle "*Back Image Click*" there and just set the respective title name in Individual Activities. All the Activities will extends *BaseActivity* excluding *MainActivity*

Comment: Yes you can check this link on Medium 
https://medium.com/@sandeeptengale/writing-good-baseactivity-class-for-android-activity-100636c81011

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Create 2 themes in styles.xml

```
 <style name="NoActionAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>

 <style name="ActionBarTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

Next In your manifest file

```
<activity
            android:name="MainActivity"
            android:label="title you want to set to action bar"
            android:theme="@style/NoActionAppTheme" />


<activity
            android:name="OtherActivity"
            android:label="title you want to set to action bar"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" // where you want go on clicking back
            android:theme="@style/ActionBarTheme" />
```

With this approach you have to make changes to styles.xml and rest will take for itself

Setting title programatically

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Some Title You Want");
```

Important to display back button

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

Comment: And the back buttons and the titles?

Comment: I have upated my answer you can use label in manifest file for each activity or set it programatically and remember theme with no action bar will throw a null pointer exception in activity if you try to set title on it for that you should use toolbar

Comment: I can set the title in the manifest but for the back button I have to use `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true)` in every Activity which I want to have a back button, right? If yes, exactly which place of the Activity do I put this line in?

Comment: add that in on create after setContentView()

Comment: It doesn't work, I put the `activity` tags in `AndroidManifest.xml` in `application` tag. Is this right? By the way I had `<style name="AppTheme" parent = "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">` in `styles.xml` comming by default when I created the app I added only `<item name = "android:textColor" > #0000ff </item>` in it because I wanted all the text of the application to be blue. There was `Theme = "@style/AppTheme"` attribute above MainActivity.cs, I replaced that with `Theme = "@style/NoActionAppTheme"` , but then none of the Activities had action bar. My project is Xamarin.Android.

Comment: sorry I think I missed it you have to android:theme="and specify the theme you want in manifest file for each activity" like we have label and name

Comment: Why do I see `android:theme=` in the `activity` tag then?